# how to sum lists in lists pairwise in python and put this sum in a new list

Tags: python

the question is pretty clear but an example:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
```

then the list I want to make is:

```
a_new = [ 1+3+5+7 , 2+4+6+8]
```

The lists within the list are always of the same length and of course I want to not only do this for two dimensions but for big numbers n as well.

So far I've tried using double for loops but I utterly failed so help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Debugging and implementation questions are off topic on Programmers.SE and best asked on StackOverflow (as described in the [help/on-topic]).

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to transpose your input lists from rows to columns, then [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) those columns:

```
[sum(col) for col in zip(*a)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
>>> zip(*a)
[(1, 3, 5, 7), (2, 4, 6, 8)]
>>> [sum(col) for col in zip(*a)]
[16, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map:

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
>>> map(sum, zip(*a))
[16, 20]
>>>
```

Comment: Take into account that in Python 3 `map()` returns an iterator, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `map()`, `zip()`, or `reduce()`, here is a pure list comprehension method using **list concatenation**:

```
[sum([x for x, y in a])]+[sum([y for x, y in a])]
```

---

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
>>> a_new = [sum([x for x, y in a])]+[sum([y for x, y in a])]
>>> a_new
[16, 20]
>>>
```

Comment: This solution won't scale with more columns.